# Ansible playbook, difficults with with_items multiples vars

Tags: yaml, ansible

I use ansible to configure a server. I have to see if some line exist and if I have to change them so I use lineinfile module. To have a code more clean I would use with_items like this:

```
- name: Postegresql configuration
  lineinfile: dest={{ item.dest }} line={{ item.line }} regexp={{ item.regexp }}
  with_items:
    - { dest: '/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf', line: 'port = 5433', regexp: '^port =' }
    - { dest: '/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf', line: 'log_truncate_on_rotation = on', regexp: '^log_truncate_on_rotation =' }
    - { dest: '/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf', line: 'log_rotation_age = 1d', regexp: '^log_rotation_age =' }
    - { dest: '/var/lib/pgsql/data/postgresql.conf', line: 'log_rotation_size = 0MB', regexp: '^log_rotation_size =' }
  notify: restart postgresql
  tags: verif
```

But it doesn't work. I he=ave this error:

```
a duplicate parameter was found in the argument string ()
```

I this it's a syntax error, can you help me ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try putting quotes around any inserted variables that you use. This will ensure that they are treated as a whole together and get parsed as you intend.

```
lineinfile: dest="{{ item.dest }}" line="{{ item.line }}" regexp="{{ item.regexp }}"
```